# How to force column width support on fluid HTML email in Outlook 2016 without using image spacer

Tags: outlook, html-email, fluid-layout

When sending the layout to Outlook 2016 it takes the multi-column table section and shrinks the width of the left and right (possibly increasing the width of the spacer center column too).

Have tried to add a spacer image at the bottom of each column to keep the width, but don't want those to have to load/soak up the file size. depending on the number of rows I add.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml "
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<title></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<meta name=”x-apple-disable-message-reformatting”>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<style type="text/css">

/*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/ 
.ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */ 
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */ 
table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */ 
#outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook 2007 and up to provide a "view in browser" message. */ 
img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} /* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */ 
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */ 


/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

/* RESET STYLES */
img { max-width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; border: 0; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
body { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; min-width:100% !important;}

/* iOS BLUE LINKS */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}

*[class=table] 
{
max-width: 600px !important;
width: 100% !important; 
border-collapse: collapse !important;    
height:auto !important; }  



/* MOBILE STYLES */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) 
{
  .img-max {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }

  .max-width {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
border-collapse: collapse !important;    
height:auto !important;
  }

  .mobile-wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
height:auto !important; 
  }

  .mobile-padding {
      padding-left: 5% !important;
    padding-right: 5% !important;
  }

.img-social {
    width: 15% !important;
    max-width: 50% !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }

*[class=stack] 
{
display: block !important;  

}
}

/* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] { margin: 0 !important; }

#actual-table { border-collapse: collapse; }
#actual-table td {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#actual-table td:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
#actual-table td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}


</style>



</head>

<body style="text-align:center; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0; !important;" >

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" background="bg.jpg" style="background-size: cover; padding: 0;background: #999999;" bgcolor="#999999" class="mobile-wrapper">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                   <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                        <a href="https://custapp.marketvolt.com/FeatureUnavailable"><font face="Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000" font="" size="1">View in browser</font></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://custapp.marketvolt.com/FeatureUnavailable"><font face="Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000" font="" size="1">Link to Forward To A Friend</font></a>   </td></tr>

</table></td></tr></table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td> <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                   <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0;">
<a href="http://example.com/"><img src="" class="banner" style="display:block;" /></a>
</td>
                </tr>
                            </table></td></tr></table>           
                    </td>
                </tr></table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #999999;" bgcolor="#999999" class="mobile-wrapper">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
               
                <tr>
                    <td class="stack" align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;background-color:#F4BB8A;" bgcolor="#F4BB8A">
                        <font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif" color="#000000" font="" size="4"><strong>Add A Headline To Announce Your Main Topic</strong></font></td></tr>
<tr>
              <td class="stack" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;background-color:#F6F7F3;" bgcolor="#F6F7F3"><font face="Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000" font="" size="3">
                          Add a brief message. If readers need to know more than you can fit here, add a link to an outside resource that covers the rest.<br />
THE MAXIMUM SIZE FOR IMAGES IN THIS SECTION IS 580px WIDE.
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<tr>
              <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#999999;" bgcolor="#999999">
&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table></td></tr></table> 
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #999999;" bgcolor="#999999" >
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;" >
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0;">
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" id="actual-table">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" width="280" style="background-color: #999999;" bgcolor="#999999" >
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:280px; vertical-align:top; width:100%; height:100%;background-color: #999999;" bgcolor="#999999" class="mobile-wrapper">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280" style="max-width:280px;" class="max-width">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10px;background-color:#999999;" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#393B63;" bgcolor="#393B63">
            <font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif" color="#F6F7F3" size="3"><strong>I &hearts; Email</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#F6F7F3;" bgcolor="#F6F7F3"><font face="Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000" size="2">Include article copy. Be sure to make the articles short and concise. People tend to only read a couple of paragraphs at a time.<br />
            <br />
            THE MAXIMUM SIZE FOR IMAGES IN THIS SECTION IS 260px WIDE.<br />
            <br />
            When editing sections from copied mailings, delete old messages by clicking the red X, move messages up or down in order of importance by clicking the blue up and down arrows and add new sections by clicking the add section here (green '+' icon).</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#999999;" bgcolor="#999999">
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td></tr></table>                            
                        </div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                        <td width="20" style="padding:0; font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" width="280" style="background-color: #999999;" bgcolor="#999999" >
                        <![endif]-->
                        <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:280px; vertical-align:top; width:100%; height:100%;background-color: #999999;" bgcolor="#999999" class="mobile-wrapper">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280" style="max-width:280px;" class="max-width">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10px;background-color:#999999;" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#393B63;" bgcolor="#393B63">
            <font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif" color="#F6F7F3" size="2"><strong>I &hearts; Email</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#F6F7F3;" bgcolor="#F6F7F3"><font face="Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000" size="2">Include article copy. Be sure to make the articles short and concise. &nbsp;</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#999999;" bgcolor="#999999">
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td></tr></table>
                                                    </div>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" bgcolor="#999999" style="background: #999999;padding: 0;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
               
                <tr>
                    <td class="stack" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;background-color:#F4BB8A;" bgcolor="#F4BB8A">
                        <font face="Times New Roman, Times, serif" color="#000000" font="" size="3"><strong>Design emails people love</strong></font></td></tr>
<tr>
              <td class="stack" align="!3BODYFONTALIGN!" valign="top" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;background-color:#FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font face="Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#000000" font="" size="2">Include article copy. Be sure to make the articles short and concise. People tend to only read a couple of paragraphs at a time.<br /><br />
THE MAXIMUM SIZE FOR IMAGES IN THIS SECTION IS 580px WIDE.
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<tr>
              <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#999999;" bgcolor="#999999">
&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table> 



</td></tr></table> 
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                                  <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" bgcolor="#0F0D35" style="background: #0F0D35;padding: 0;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="stack" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:10px;background-color:#0F0D35;" bgcolor="#0F0D35">
                        <font face="Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#FFFFFF" font="" size="2"></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td></tr></table> 
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                                  <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #0F0D35;" bgcolor="#0F0D35" class="mobile-wrapper">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
            <![endif]-->
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"> <tr>   <td colspan="3">     <hr align="left" width="100%" noshade>     <p>       <font size="-2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color=         "#FFFFFF"><strong>Generated by</strong></font> <a href=         "http://www.marketvolt.com" target="_blank"><img src=         "https://images.marketvolt.com/mv_gif_transparent.gif" width="60" height="55"         hspace="4" vspace="0" border="0" align="middle"></a><a href=         "http://www.marketvolt.com" target="_blank" style=         "text-decoration: none;"><font size="-2" face=         "Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color=         "#FFFFFF"><strong>Learn more</strong></font></a>     </p>   </td> </tr></table><img width="1" height="1" src="https://images.marketvolt.com/space.gif">
         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which section are you referring to exactly?
I'm not seeing any issues in Outlook 2016 that don't already appear when just viewing in a browser.

Comment: This is the how it renders in our Outlook. See multi column section. [link](https://images.marketvolt.com/Client/5457309_734584534.PNG)